# MDM prompting for password

Tags: iphone

I have been using Cisco Meraki for mdm and its has been working fine. I have observed today that it is asking for a shared mailboxes password after an ios gets updated. Can you guys help me out?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please add more information to your question? Are you a user or an MDM or Meraki admin? Can you please edit your question to clear up what your problem is and what you’ve done to try to solve it?